# Deploying expo app error: Build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error

Tags: react-native, deployment, expo

Build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeLMq.png)

why am I getting this error?

using:

npx expo-doctor --fix-dependencies

also gives me an error:

(node:4132) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

I think the issue is with some conflicting dependencies

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error and I ran following commands:
expo doctor
expo doctor --fix-dependencies

After these commands the error is gone.

Comment: running that command I get:   node:4132) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The punycode module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead. (Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)